# How exactly is LinkedList<T> and LinkedListNode<T> implemented in C#? And how exactly does LinkedList<T>.Remove(LinkedListNode<T>) work?

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list, deep-copy

I researched online that the inbuilt LinkedList is a Doubly LinkedList in C#. I also researched on the LinkedList.Remove(LinkedListNode) method. But I still couldn't find the answer to my question.
Following is the code snippet:

```
    public string DequeueCat()
    {
        LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;
        while (temp != null && temp.Value.Contains("Cat") == false)
        {
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        if (temp!=null && temp.Value.Contains("Cat"))
        {
            animals.Remove(temp);
            return temp.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No more Cats available");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The variable `animals` is of type `LinkedList<string>`.
What exactly happens when we instantiate a fresh `LinkedListNode<string>` with `animals.First`? Such as `LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;`.
Does a Deep Copy occur and, the original LinkedList (pointed by `animals.First`), gets copied over to `temp`, at a new location on the Heap?
Also, when we write `animals.Remove(temp)`, the `temp` LinkListNode is destroyed. And, the corresponding value is removed from the `animals` LinkedList.

Following is the watch window before executing `animals.Remove(temp)` -
[image: Watch window before executing animals.Remove(temp)]

And, following is the Watch window AFTER executing `animals.Remove(temp)` -
[image: Watch window AFTER executing animals.Remove(temp)]

My question is that, why is `temp` destroyed, after executing `animals.Remove(temp)`? Also, if `temp` has been created at a separate place on the Heap (as compared to the original LinkedList), then how do we know that Removing `temp` from the original, `animals` LinkedList will remove the corresponding item from
the `animals` LinkedList?

Following is the entire code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AnimalShelter
{
    class AnimalsShelter
    {
        //This class will have the following functions: 
        //Enqueue, DequeueAny, DeQueueDog, DeQueueCat
        //Implement queue using C# inbuilt linked list.
        LinkedList<string> animals = new LinkedList<string>();
        public void Enqueue(string animal)
        {
            animals.AddLast(animal);
        }

        public string DequeueAny()
        {
            LinkedListNode<string> firstAnimal = animals.First;
            if (firstAnimal != null)
            {
                animals.RemoveFirst();
                return firstAnimal.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more animanls left in queue.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string DequeueDog()
        {
            LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;
            while(temp!=null && temp.Value.Contains("Dog")==false)
            {
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
            if(temp!=null && temp.Value.Contains("Dog"))
            {
                animals.Remove(temp);
                return temp.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more Dogs available");
                return null;
            }
        }

        public string DequeueCat()
        {
            LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;
            while (temp != null && temp.Value.Contains("Cat") == false)
            {
                temp = temp.Next;
            }
            if (temp!=null && temp.Value.Contains("Cat"))
            {
                animals.Remove(temp);
                return temp.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No more Cats available");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AnimalsShelter shelter = new AnimalsShelter();
            shelter.Enqueue("Dog1");
            shelter.Enqueue("Dog2");
            shelter.Enqueue("Cat1");
            shelter.Enqueue("Dog3");
            shelter.Enqueue("Cat2");
            shelter.Enqueue("Cat3");
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueCat());
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueAny());
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueDog());
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueCat());
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueAny());
            Console.WriteLine(shelter.DequeueAny());
        }
    }
}
```

Any light on this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs

Comment: @SeanReid, Thank you for your pointer! So, when we say `LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First`;. Both `temp` and `animals.First` are on the Stack, and they point to the same `LinkedListNode` on the Heap. Correct? Also, the `animals` variable is on the Stack, and points to the `LinkedList` on the Heap. And when we say `animals.Remove(temp)`, the `LinkedListNode` pointed by `temp` is removed from `animals`. Correct? Also both the `temp` variable and the `animals` variable are on the Stack , and they point to the `LinkedListNode` and the `LinkedList` on the Heap, respectively. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The variable animals is of type `LinkedList<string>`. What exactly
> happens when we instantiate a fresh `LinkedListNode<string>` with
> `animals.First`? Such as `LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;`.
> Does a Deep Copy occur

No. All you have done is copy a reference `LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;`

> Also, when we write `animals.Remove(temp)`, the temp `LinkListNode` is
> destroyed.

No. It's not being destroyed, however its linkages are being removed. It's still the same reference.

> My question is that, why is temp destroyed, after executing
> animals.Remove(temp)?

No. Once again it's not being destroyed. however its linkages are being removed.

> Also, if temp has been created at a separate place on the Heap

No. It hasn't been created at a separate place on the heap, all you did is copy the reference.

> then how do we know that Removing temp from the original, animals
> LinkedList will remove the corresponding item from the animals
> LinkedList

We know, because it was the same object / same reference.

Here is an approximation of the code for `Remove`. As you can see there is no magic:

```
internal void InternalRemoveNode(LinkedListNode<T> node) 
{

     ...

     if ( node.next == node)
            head  = null;      
     else 
     {
         node.next.prev = node.prev;
         node.prev.next = node.next;
         if ( head == node) 
             head = node.next;
     }
     node.Invalidate();  
     count--;
     version++;          
}
```

---

**Further Reading**

[Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types.
> Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects),
> while variables of value types directly contain their data. With
> reference types, two variables can reference the same object;
> therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced
> by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own
> copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one
> variable to affect the other (except in the case of in, ref and out
> parameter variables; see in, ref and out parameter modifier).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, when we say `LinkedListNode<string> temp = animals.First;`. Both `temp` and `animals.First` are on the Stack, and they point to the same `LinkedListNode`on the Heap. Correct? Also, the `animals` variable is on the Stack, and points to the `LinkedList`on the Heap. And when we say `animals.Remove(temp)`, the `LinkedListNode` pointed by `temp` is removed from `animals`. Correct? Also both the `temp` variable and the `animals` variable are on the Stack , and they point to the `LinkedListNode` and the `LinkedList` on the Heap, respectively. Correct?